# 0.3 is converted to 0.300000011920929 in SQL Server when adding from .NET Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, numeric

I have a table in SQL Server that has a column with datatype `float`. I wrote a stored procedure for inserting the record and it also accepts the parameter as `float`.

However Entity Framework generated the method with datatype `double`. So when I add 0.3 from my .NET client, it is changed to 0.300000011920929 however I need to add the exact value I added that is 0.3.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) It's just how binary floating points work

Comment: Suggest you read this [floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) if you want to understand why this happens. And you should read it.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/861716

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, as in other languages, the `float` data type cannot be used to store exact base<sub>10</sub> decimal values because a `float` does not always have an exact representation (https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/). Try using the `decimal` data type instead, which in SQL is designed to store decimal values precisely.

See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Of course they can be used to store exact values, they just have to be base2 fractions (eg 0.5 or 0.25 decimal), which 0.3 (decimal) is not

Comment: @Charlieface, good point. I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: When I am inserting a record with an insert statement, it inserts the exact value but in .NET it is mapped with double data type and hence the approximate value is passed from the .NET client.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, I couldn't understand the point, can you please elaborate more? At this stage it is hard to change the data type from float to decimal, is there any other way to keep the float datatype and store the exact value?

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAlam Please read up on how floating point math works. You are not inserting the exact value because the value you have does not have an exact representation in floating point, neither in .NET or in SQL. If you want to store an exact decimal the use the `decimal` type